# google places API ignoring location, radius and strictbounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to use the google places api to auto-complete a text field but it is currently returning results from all over the world and I would like to restrict the results to Perth, Australia which ostensibly has the coordinates of -31.93333, 115.83333 and use a radius of 50km. I have tried

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&v=3.exp&libraries=places&location=-31.93333,115.83333&radius=50000

which doesn't bias results to this location in the slightest and also
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&v=3.exp&libraries=places&location=-31.93333,115.83333&radius=50000&strictbounds
which doesn't change it's behaviour in the slightest. The only thing that's had any effect has been to restrict results to australia in the init code

```
function init() {
  var input = document.getElementById('address');
  var componentRestrictions = {country: 'au'};
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(componentRestrictions);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

But this creates more strange behaviour such as only returning 1 suggestion on the first digit entered. According to my google dashboard no errors are present.

Comment: I don't see `strictbounds` in their documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: Also, have you tried using `nearbysearch` as the specific place search? I don't see that in your url.

Comment: I got the strictbounds from https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete - I also found reference to a boolean strictBounds on another page somewhere, will try changing case and nearbysearch and get back to you if that works

Comment: In any event, I do not see "autocomplete" in your url. You need to specify what API you want to make use of or it won't give you any information you want. Specifically, the url should look like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/output?parameters`

Comment: I've tried adding place/nearbysearch and place/autocomplete to the url and it causes it to fail completely saying google is not defined. The URL I've posted does work it just doesn't do any location biasing.

Comment: Yes, you will have to both import the API and make http calls separately. One will be `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>` which simply imports the library, and the HTTP calls you're making above are done elsewhere to actually get data.